# Issues with setting DKIM records for mandrill

Tags: email, dns, mailchimp, mandrill, dkim

I'm sending e-mails using API provided by Mandrill/Mailchimp and trying to authenticate e-mails by adding the SPF and DKIM records for sending domains.

I have done everything according to [Mandrill documentation](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582277-How-do-I-add-DNS-records-for-my-sending-domains-).

For SPF record everything is going smoothly but for DKIM record authentication Mandrill is having some difficulties:
http://grab.by/JkQs

And consequently Mandrill overwrites 'from' headers of e-mails:
http://grab.by/JkQC

Has anyone faced with similar problem and could someone help me please to work around the issue?

P.S. After testing with third party DKIM validator (http://dkimcore.org/tools/keycheck.html) I got a message: 'This is a valid DKIM key record'.

Comment: Your DKIM info definitely looks to be set up correctly, so it's possible there's some sort of intermittent issue with your DNS that's preventing Mandrill from being able to validate the record. For example, trying to resolve even your root domain w/various resolvers (OpenDNS, Google, etc.), one attempt will timeout and the next attempt several seconds to a minute later will work as expected. May be worth reaching out to your DNS provider for support?

Comment: I'll do that, thanks!